# using keyword results in error when forward declaring specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, using

say i have a class A which is templatized in some namespace NameSpaceA.

i wish to use the forward declaration in some other header file . I am able to achieve this using the following syntax

```
File 1.h

namespace NameSpaceA
{
    template <typename T>
    class A
    {
    public:
        void foo();
    }
}
```

**code that works for me**

```
File 2.h

//forward declaration
namespace NameSpaceA
{
    template <typename T>
    class A;
}

class B
{
private:
    vector<NameSpaceA::A<specialization>* > mABC;
}
```

but i want to code it with the **using** keyword.

I tried the following syntax

(**code that fails**)

```
File 2.h
//forward declaration
namespace NameSpaceA
{
    template <typename T>
    class A;
}

using A = typename NameSpaceA::A<specialization>;

class B
{
private:
    vector<A>* > mABC;
}
```

**but vector declaration errors out with the message template argument 1 is invalid**. Can someone please help me write this elegant way.

Comment: Please provide a proper [repro] that generates the error message and add that error message complete and verbatim. You current code is insufficient to properly answer and full of syntax errors.

Comment: what's the actual error message

Comment: The first snippet has multiple syntax errors. Please [edit] your question to include code that actually reproduces the error you are seeing.

Comment: @uneven_mark  I have updated the question

Comment: @NikhilChauhan Please read the link I posted again. A [repro] means that I can copy-paste the code into files without change, run the compiler and get the same result as you got. This fails here: There are no `#include` statements, `specialization` and `vector` are undeclared, there are multiple missing semicolons, one `>` that certainly does not belong in the code, etc.

Comment: @NikhilChauhan Can't reproduce. [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bGy1sp9uWflZE6H2)

Comment: @super agreed i tried in wandbox trying to replicate exact scenario but it compiles fine. I think its the problem with my compiler , boost  is used in my work place

Comment: Why do you not provide the error message?